# How to add Jquery ajax to an existing form with Javascript submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

I have a form that I need to enhance it with JQuery Ajax. Currently, its using javascript to handle submission. When the user hits the submit button, the control is going to a javascript function and the javascript function does some processing and then does the form-id.submit().

Now how can I introduce JQuery-ajax to the current form? I don't want to recreate the whole javascript function in JQuery and then do the JQuery submit. Is there a way to pass the form object/values to Jquery in existing the javascript function and then do the submission using Jquery-ajax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a jQuery plugin for that. http://jquery.malsup.com/form

Use the [`beforeSubmit` option](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) to execute your pre-submit function.

Comment: thanks! Also currently the submit button has the "onclick="update_function('form-id')" code. Do I just get rid of that and then use jquery to catch the click event and then run the update_function('form-id') javascript function? Also how do I call the javascript function from jquery? is it just straightforward like writing a new line of "update_function('$form_id')" after setting up $form_id field with the actual form id?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, there's pretty much no need for `onclick` attributes anymore. Yes, you can/should use jQuery to bind event handlers instead. jQuery is JavaScript, so yes you "call the javascript function from jquery" as described.

Answer (score 1):

when a form submits to the backend, you get serialized data. If you want to keep your same backend (obviously have it send a return response instead of writing to the page or whatever) just use `$('#form').serialize();` as your data when you send it.